# Video recording in java using java media framework is throwing exception

Tags: java, jmf

For capture the live video from web using java and jmf i have written the below code , I plugin the usb webcam and i have installed java mediaframewrok latest and updated version.when i complie the program there is no error but while i run the program i got some error like this....

```
    Exception in thread "VFW Request Thread" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: JMFSecurityManager: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jmvfw in java.library.path at com.sun.media.JMFSecurityManager.loadLibrary(JMFSecurityManager.java:
206)
        at com.sun.media.protocol.vfw.VFWCapture.<clinit>(VFWCapture.java:19)
        at com.sun.media.protocol.vfw.VFWSourceStream.doConnect(VFWSourceStream.
java:241)
        at com.sun.media.protocol.vfw.VFWSourceStream.run(VFWSourceStream.java:7
63)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: Is it Windows, Linux or OS X? Have you checked your path for the `jmvfw` lib?

Comment: it is Windows and i have inserted path of jmf all libraries in class path in environment variable

Comment: Have you checked that this library is on your path (property "java.library.path")?

Comment: i don't know how to check this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should load the library like this (and can check the library path if it has been loaded.):

```
   public class Test {

      static {
        try {
            System.load("C:/PATH_TO/jmvfw.dll");
            System.out.println(String.format("%s has been successfully loaded","jmvfw"));
        } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
          System.err.println("Native code library jmvfw  failed to load." , e);
          System.exit(1);
        }
      }
      //check if the lib is in java.library.path
      public static void main(String argv[]) {
        String libs = System.getProperty("java.library.path");
        for (String lib : libs.split(";")) 
            System.out.println(lib);

      }
    }
```

## Update

The error:

```
C:\jmvfw.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
```

means that your DLL is 32-bit. You have to recompile (or download) the DLL for 64-bit. Another option is to switch to a 32-bit JVM -- or get some 32-bit process to load the DLL on your behalf and communicate with that process (a bit complicated).

Comment: it displaying this error ...                                             java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\jmvfw.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD
 64-bit platform

Comment: Your `DLL` is 32-bit, you have to recompile (or download) the `DLL` for 64-bit. You can switch to a 32-bit JVM, or otherwise get some 32-bit process to load the `DLL` on your behalf and communicate with that process somehow.